# PowerShell Test-Connection is returning that a device is down when it is not

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code in PowerShell to ping multiple devices and return whether they are up or down.

```
$Output= @()
$names = Get-content "C:\HHM\hnames.txt"
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 4 -Delay 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= "$name,up"
   Write-Host "$Name,up"
  }
  else{
    $Output+= "$name,down"
    Write-Host "$Name,down"
  }
}
$Output | Out-file "C:\HHM\result.csv"
```

When I check some of the devices that are listed as down, they are actually up. Given the nature of these devices, I do not believe that the connection is intermittent and the connection was actually down when the code was run. Would any of the other Test-Connection Parameters potentially help this? I've already used Count 4 and Delay 2, but I'm not sure if any of the other parameters will solve the issue.

EDIT - Just to clarify, I am getting the correct up/down status most of the time. Every once and a while, the code will return that a device is down, but when I go to check the device, I have a connection.

Comment: `Test-Connection` does a ping echo, nothing more. If you want to test whether you can establish a TCP connection on a given port/service, use `Test-NetConnection`

Comment: Have you tried by IP's? Could be a DNS issue.

Comment: Windows firewall blocks ping by default

Comment: If the issue comes and goes then you need to do some network troubleshooting. Not an issue with your code nor something this site fit to help you with. You would find better advise in Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your problem, but you didn't specify if the devices have a static IP or dynamic IP.  If dynamic, I would suggest always running `ipconfig /flushdns` prior to running your script.  I can not begin to tell you how many times I thought a device was down, or thought I was connecting to one device only to discover I was connecting to another device.

Comment: I am using static IP's.